# How to get List from future list function in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, https

I'm creating an app that use assets_audio_player to play music from a json response that are generated from a php script. There is a Future list function that return an Audio list. Audio isn't a Widget so i can't use a FutureBuilder. How can i use the future list?

```
    Future<List<Audio>> creaLista() async {
      final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url));
      String responseBody = response.body;

      dynamic jsonObject = json.decode(responseBody);

      final convertedJsonObject = jsonObject.cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

      List<Song> list =
          convertedJsonObject.map<Song>((json) => Song.fromJson(json)).toList();

      List<Audio> audioList = list
          .map<Audio>((json) => Audio.network(
                urlSong + json.url,
                metas: Metas(
                  title: json.title,
                  artist: json.artist,
                  album: json.album,
                  image: MetasImage.network(
                    urlImage + json.image,
          ),
        ),
      ))
    .toList();
  

    return audioList;
    }
```

This is the Song class:

```
    class Song {
      String title;
      String artist;
      String album;
      String image;
      String genre;
      String url;
    
      Song(
          {required this.title,
          required this.artist,
          required this.album,
          required this.image,
          required this.genre,
          required this.url});

      factory Song.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Song(
          title: json['title'],
          artist: json['artist'],
          album: json['album'],
          image: json['image'],
          genre: json['genre'],
          url: json['url']);
    }
```

This is the json response:

```
    [{"title":"Mille","artist":"Fedez, Achille Lauro, Orietta Berti","album":"Singolo","image":"mille.jpg","genre":"pop","url":"mille.mp3"}]
```

Comment: Have you tried from an async function calling this with await, like 'final audioList = await creaLista();'?

Comment: To know how you can use the future list, you probably want to expand of what consumes the list and how it consumes it.

Comment: Please share the expected output from the HTTP request for better understanding. You can also clarify whether Audio and Song are two different models.

Comment: [{"title":"Mille","artist":"Fedez, Achille Lauro, Orietta Berti","album":"Singolo","image":"mille.jpg","genre":"pop","url":"mille.mp3"}]

Comment: i cannot use an async function because i need to fill the List<Audio> in the initState()

Comment: Why do you need to call it in `initState`? Just pass the async function into the `future` property of the `FutureBuilder` and it will run and populate your list. That's the whole point of a `FutureBuilder`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `Future` to return a `Widget` to use `FutureBuilder`. You can create widgets based on the returned results of the future. Here's an example that would display the just the artist, but it should give you the idea.

In general I would suggest creating a custom `Widget` that takes an `Audio` object and displays all of the `Audio` data how you would like.

```
FutureBuilder(
          future: creaLista(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              final audioList = snapshot.data as List<Audio>;
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: audioList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Text(audioList[index].artist);
                  });
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              // handle error here
              return Text('${snapshot.error}');
            } else {
              return CircularProgressIndicator(); // displays while loading data
            }
          },
        )
```

This assumes your `Audio` class looks like this

```
class Audio {
  String title, artist, album;
  Audio(this.title, this.artist, this.album);
}
```

I'm sure its more complex than that but it should give you the idea.